# How can I edit the "Save as type:" list in the "Save As" dialog box in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

The list of supported files is too long and I'd like to shorten it:

[image: Notepad++ Save as file list]

I vaguely remember that I used to be able to do this.

Comment: Another tip to go along with @Toto's answer: You can force a file type when you save by putting the filename appended with type extension in quotes. For example, if i wanted to save an example html file, i could just save as `"examplefilename.html"` and it would force it to save as an html regardless of what "save as type" option is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose:

> Settings > preferences > Languages

Move unwanted languages from available to hidden